# Playing MIDI in Java Applet pauses the Applet

Tags: java, multithreading, midi

I´m writing a Java Applet containing an animation which triggers a MIDI-sound to be played. The sound is played by the following class - which starts its own Thread - anyway the animation in the Applet is paused while the sound plays. I don´t see what i did wrong here, I would expect the animation not to pause due to the newly assigned Thread...

```
import java.util.logging.Level;
import java.util.logging.Logger;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiChannel;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem;
import javax.sound.midi.MidiUnavailableException;
import javax.sound.midi.Synthesizer;

public class ChromaticSynth implements Runnable{
    //vars
    private Synthesizer synth;
    private MidiChannel mchannel;
    private int playNote;
    private Thread myThread;

    //constructor
    public ChromaticSynth(int playNote){
        try {
            synth=MidiSystem.getSynthesizer();
            synth.open();
            mchannel=synth.getChannels()[0];
            this.playNote=playNote;

            myThread=new Thread(this);
            myThread.start();
        } catch (MidiUnavailableException ex) {
            Logger.getLogger(ChromaticSynth.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }


     }

    //play sound
    public void run(){
        mchannel.noteOn(playNote,50);
    }
}
```

The ChromaticSynth class is used in the following way (in reduced the code to the relevant part):

```
import chromatic.ChromaticSynth;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class ChromaticPanel extends JPanel{
    //vars
    ...

    //constructor
    public ChromaticPanel(){
        super();
        ...
    }

    //paint
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g){

        super.paintComponent(g);

       //draw something
        g.setColor(Color.white);
        g.draw(...);

       if(noteshouldbeplayed)
            ChromaticSynth cs=new ChromaticSynth(playNote);                    

    }


}
```

The Panel's repaint()-Method is called repeatedly by a javax.swing.Timer in the JFrame containing the ChromaticPanel to paint the animation.

thx for your help!

Comment: some source in the internet says midi can be a security hole sometimes. be careful

Comment: How do you use your `ChromaticSynth` class? How do you start the thread?

Comment: @assylias I edited the question to include your comment!

Comment: Have you tried moving all the code from your ChromaticSynth constructor into its run() method? Does that solve the problem? There may be threading constraints on the MIDI api, for instace some kind of synchronized, stopping you from getting channels until old channels have been returned...

Comment: Can't you post a proper SSCCE, if your problem is so confidential why did you even bother to ask ?? Your second class seems useless remove few elements and make it work so that every one can spot the problem easily

Comment: I honestly do not know what you mean by this @Sanyam Goel

Comment: Short, Self Contained, Correct Example (SSCCE) please go through this link  http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22754/sscce-how-to-provide-examples-for-programming-questions